# Persistent, dictionary-like object ensurance

Tags: python, python-2.x

This is a part of a project I'm working on. The codebase is Python 2.7 and I don't have an option to switch to Python 3.

Code:

```
import shelve
def get_document_info():
    token_shelf = False

    try:
        token_shelf = shelve.open(os.path.join(current_dir, 'document_info.shelve'))
        token_mapping = token_shelf['token_mapping']

        if token_mapping:
            return token_mapping
        else:
            return False

    except Exception, e:
        pass

    finally:
        if token_shelf:
            token_shelf.close()
```

Shelve is a persistent, dictionary-like object. More info can be found at https://docs.python.org/2/library/shelve.html

I need to ensure that `token_shelf` is closed at the end. In the beginning of the function, what do I define `token_shelf` as? If I don't define something there, PyCharm will throw an error saying that the `token_shelf` in `finally` block does not exist.

What's the ideal way to write this piece of code? How can it be made more elegant and Pythonic?

**PS: This code is working as expected right now.**

Comment: Welcome to codereview! What is `shelve`? A file? Please post all the code or at least add some context about what this code is supposed to do. And it's python 2.x or 3.x? Is this your code? So many questions...

Comment: @MrGrj: Updated the post. Is there anything else I'm missing? Please let me know.

Comment: Please add the import too. More, does this code work as expected?

Comment: This is not stackoverflow. How does a _shelve_ file look like? What is `current_dir`? Where is the `os` imported? I don't see it in the code -> I can't run the code -> the question is off-topic. If you want help from us, you first have to let us help you by understanding **all** your code

Comment: Which exceptions are you guarding against?

Answer (score 4):

Ideally you would want to use Python's `with ... as` syntax, which creates a context that calls the exit method of whatever object you create. For this, the `shelve.Shelf` classes would need to implement the dunder methods `__enter__` and `__exit__` (which they don't).

At this point you basically have three options:

1. Inherit from them and implement it yourself:

```
class Shelf(shelve.Shelf):

    def __new__(cls, file_name):
        return shelve.open(file_name)

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        self.close()
```

2. Or just write a simple wrapper class like this:

```
class Shelf(object):

    def __init__(self, file_name):
        self.file_name = file_name

    def __enter__(self):
        self.obj = shelve.open(self.file_name)
        return self.obj

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        self.obj.close()
```

Both can be used like this:

```
import os
import shelve

def get_document_info(current_dir):
    shelf_path = os.path.join(current_dir, 'document_info.shelve')
    with Shelf(shelf_path) as token_shelf:
        return token_shelf.get('token_mapping')
```

When you use `try..except` you should always guard against as specific exceptions as possible (so that unexpected exceptions can still rise to the top). In this case this would probably be a `KeyError`. Here I used the `get` method instead, which will return `None` if the key is not found.

I also removed the `return False`, because you should check for falsiness in the calling code. In other words, if you are doing `if token_mapping is False` or  `if token_mapping == False` in the calling code, you are doing it wrong. Just have the `if not token_mapping`/`if token_mapping` there.

3. Use Python's [`contextlib.closing`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.closing), which already implements something like option 2:

```
from contextlib import closing
import os
import shelve

def get_document_info(current_dir):
    shelf_path = os.path.join(current_dir, 'document_info.shelve')
    with closing(shelve.open(shelf_path)) as token_shelf:
        return token_shelf.get('token_mapping')
```

Comment: Nice. That's indeed the correct way to do what OP requested! +1

Comment: Could you explain why in the `Shelf` class `__new__` is implemented, and not `__init__`?

Comment: @mkrieger1 Because I inherit from `shelve.Shelf`, so it is already implemented. Also note that the `open` function is not a method of the original class, but a module function, so I needed some way to return the right object upon creation. It would also have been possible to set `self.file_name` in `__init__`, though and do the opening in the `__enter__` method.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I added the version without overwriting `__new__`.

Answer (score -3):

```
def get_document_info():

global token_mapping

try:
    return token_mapping if (token_mapping = shelve.open(os.path.join(current_dir, 'document_info.shelve'))['token_mapping']) else None

except Exception, e:
    token_shelf.close()
    pass
```

---

Forcibly changed your return of False as that is bad practice as you can't substitute the shelve object everywhere unless you pre-wrap it in conditionals -- always. Honestly been a decade since I wrote anything in Python. So this is what I have pieced together from quick look-ups on tutorials online. Perhaps Python has more elegantly looking Ternary Operators (Perl is nice because it has default-ly named variables).

But, even then I never forgot that Python is a Dynamically-Typed language and that every variable is just a Reference to an instance and every instance is Strongly-typed.

Comment: Please keep your negative thoughts about people to yourself. Remember to be nice.